# Dell inspiron 5570( AMD Radeon 530 ), its really lagging playing games

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon, gaming, lag

i bought dell inspiron 5570 about 2 years ago, as you maybe know this laptop has AMD Radeon 530 graphic and 8G ram and 128G ssd and a i7-8550U processor. i installed last version of graphic card driver and when i want to play a game like farcry 3 at the minimum graphic setting it just lag like hell, and also playing dota 2 make me regret about buying this laptop, just tell me if its normal or im doing something wrong, i'm tired of searching please help me.
once i set windows task manager on always on top and started dota 2, on the performance tab none of the ram, cpu and graphic card was over 40% usage but game was lagging.
i searched on the internet and i know AMD Radeon 530 can even handle GTA V on 30 fps. i don't know what is wrong with my laptop.
PS: my laptop start heating when i run a game, i think its normal.

Comment: AMD Radeon 530 is a low end GPU. Don't expect anything more FPS wise from this.

Comment: Agreed. Plus, it depends on how much graphical memory your GPU has. It can accomodate up to 2GB, but maybe yours has less than that. Check that in Speccy. Also, those games write a lot to disk. You could try to use a RAM disk along with a moderately-sized pagefile to speed things up. I know a lot of people disagree on that here, but it's worth a try.

Comment: it has 4G dedicated ram and 4G shared

Comment: @Didier - I'll be one of those in disagreement in this case;) 8GB RAM is nowhere near enough to be playing with RAMDisks. One thing I'd check is that the games are actually using the AMD & not the built-in Intel 620, which is even slower. I'd also make sure you have *at least* 20GB free space on that drive. Low RAM, low-spec GPU **and** a teeny little SSD full to the brim is a bad combination.

Comment: @Tetsujin i disabled Intel 620 in the device manager and result was the same.

Comment: I agree with you, @Tetsujin, on checking which GPU is doing most of the hevy lifting, and about how full the SSD is (plus it may not be a top-of-the-line SSD to begin with), but for the RAM disk, I disagree. I know from experience that adding one, even of moderate size, and pointing applications cache to it, can really speed things up where it matters. In games, it's graphics, and if you can relieve your PC by by-passing pagefile, even partly, your machine will work faster. EDIT: it would also ease the heating issue the OP mentions, which is probably caused by his machine paging like crazy.

Comment: @Didier - I've never tested this empirically [I don't have any machine with less than 32GB RAM I could try it out on easily] but to my mind, if you fill the system RAM & also set up a RAMDisk, then the RAMDisk too will get paged. That's going to give you a double-hit. The RAMDisk will show up as its own process, taking up system RAM - it no longer 'belongs' to the system & will be treated like any other RAM-hungry background process.

Comment: The key in using a RAM disk is: 1) Set the size good, so as not to uselessly deprive the machine of precious RAM; 2) Use dynamically allocated memory, not fixed size (ImDisk does that very well: https://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1837-create-a-ram-disk-in-windows), along with AWE (requires admin rights) to keep paging to a bare minimum; 3) Point applications cache and profile temp folders to the RAM disk (I do that with Firefox and Chrome, for example). With that in mind, you can make a PC faster, reduce wear on an SSD, and keep the whole thing stable.